# Name not matched in creating zip folder with bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a zip folder in a bash script that contains the current date (YYYY_MM_DD).
I have this code:

```
currentArchive=$(date '+%Y_%m_%d')
zip -r ./aktuell ./Archive/${currentArchive}-bkt
```

But when I run the script I get the following error:

> zip warning: name not matched: ./Archive/2017_03_30-bkt

I want the folder "aktuell" as a zip folder named "2017_03_30-bkt.zip" in the folder "Archive". The current folder "aktuell" exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change the order of args. `zip -r zipfile.zip dir`

Comment: @Fabian did that answer your question? Please accept the answer if so.

Answer (score 1):

You have the source and destination directories backwards in your zip command. Also, make sure the destination directory exists before executing zip.

```
currentArchive=$(date '+%Y_%m_%d')
mkdir -p ./Archive/
zip -r ./Archive/${currentArchive}-bkt ./aktuell
```